# Separate files for functions outside classes

Tags: function, class, oop

1. It's a good practice to separate each class from the main code using
   **headers** and **sources**. But what about functions? Let's say, I have a
   function I would like to use across multiple classes and I **don't**
   want to include this function as a method of a class.
2. If I decide to create a separate file for this function(s), should I
   put everything inside **.h** or should I do as I do with classes
   (separate **.h** and **.cpp**)?

Comment: google **Utility Class**. like [this](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html). However, I think your question is too broad now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, whether it's a class or not it's still good practice to separate the declaration / signature (in the header file) from the definition / implementation (in the cpp file).

The code that calls the function does not need to know about how the function actually works - just how to call it.

This separation can avoid circular references that can sometimes otherwise occur. It avoids the compiler having to re-parse the definition every time the declaration is included.

Basically the reasons for separation between header and cpp are much the same for class and non-class functions.

However if you're using templates you will need to include the definition not just the declaration ( as you would with template classes ).

I'd suggest you put the functions in a namespace even if you don't put them in a class.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!